# date system on SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

i just code some query which the database contain data "id and date"

```
003 18/01/1994
004 30/10/2007
005 31/08/1991
```

and i run query

```
select id from table where  (date >= #31/01/2017#)
```

the result  showing only id 005
and if i run

```
select id from table where  (date <= #31/01/2017#)
```

the result is id 003 and 004 which is i think the correct query why did the id 5 did not show up instead show up if the operator >= ? can any one help me? what is wrong?

Comment: The first query should not return anything at all based on your data.

Comment: yes, but it return id 005, instead id 005 did not show up on second querry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really expect the date `August 31, 1991` to appear as being *later* than `January 31, 2017`?  The issue is that you are not really comparing dates numerically, you are comparing strings.  You should be storing your date information in the form `yyyy-mm-dd`, something like this:

```
003 1994/01/18
004 2007/10/30
005 1991/08/31
```

Now, if you run your first query:

```
select id from table where date >= #2017/01/31#
```

you will get back empty set, and if you run the second query

```
select id from table where date <= #2017/01/31#
```

you should get back all records.

Comment: thanks, its correct, my data type before was text, so i change it to date, and its work